# DVDs have only roughly 2 KB of space

Tags: 13.04, dvd, disk-usage

I have several DVD-R 4.7 GB disks and when I enter them into my computers disk tray, Ubuntu only reads 2.0 KB. It is different for each disk, but it is always roughly around 2.0 KB and all 50 or so disks that are in this pack seem to be affected. I do not have any other disks to try and check if I somehow managed to get a bad pack, but in the past, in different installations of Ubuntu, these disks have worked just fine. I used to use them to burn Play Station 2 games. I have yet to try these disks in another computer, but I have no access to another computer.

Comment: So I just went out and bought a new pack of disks to try, this time 4.7 GB DVD+R and it seems to be only 2.0 KB on the spot with each disk.

Comment: I was also able to try them on another laptop and they worked, flawlessly. The laptop runs Windows 7.

Comment: Which software are you using to burn the DVD?

Comment: I'm using Brasero in Ubuntu and PowerISO on a Windows VM In VirtualBox. It doesn't matter what image burner I'm using because I can't even use the disk in Nautilus. When I open Disks though is the only time I can even tell because Ubuntu has been stupid with disks since 12.10 anyway

Comment: What do you mean you can't use in Nautilus?

Comment: I mean when I try to open a disk in Nautilus, it won't properly open. I can see that there is a disk mounted in the optical drive just above the, "Computer" link, but that is about as far as it goes. In the past, I have been able to use the disks like a USB drive (Obviously only in disks I set up to do so in). Now when I click the disk, it brings me to a blank screen in which I can do absolutely nothing. This includes clicking, "Write to Disk" or anything else. I have written to the disks and they are set up like a USB system with photos on them. As for disks with photos, they are the size of.

Comment: what ever is on them. For example, two of my disks hold about 75 MB and 147 MB. Instead of being 2 KB the disk size of those two DVDs are 75 MB and 147 MB. I know I should have added more information, but I have simply been ignoring this problem for so long because I couldn't find anything via search. I still don't remember all the problems I had, but I am re-experiencing them as I go. Please, if any information would help, let me know ASAP. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue.  I used [K3b](http://www.kde.org/applications/multimedia/k3b/), or [Xfburn](http://writtenandread.net/xfburn/) and problem solved.

To install click [**K3b** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/k3b/)

To install click [**Xfburn** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/xfburn/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you did, but in that program (K3b), and that program alone, the disks are read perfectly. In Nautilus and other burning programs it still only says 2.0 KB, but at least now I can use the disks. I still can't use them for the way I intended (as they are not working on the VM still and I'm just trying to use the Microsoft Installation USB/CD program to make a Windows 7 installation disc because his computer doesn't work with USBs). Anyway, thank you so much. Just to let you know, Mitch, you have helped me out a lot and I truly appreciate it.

Comment: I have come across your answers on here more than just five or six times. Thank you. I will still wait a day or so to pick my accepted answer, but if nothing shows to completely fix the problem, I will be marking your's